# How can I read a String array index from a JComboBox into a JLabel?

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I have a ComboBox holding a String[]'s values.  I have several other String[]'s holding numbers.  I want the user to be able to select a item from the ComboBox(holding my String[] names) and according to which one they pick, I want that index associated with one of my other arrays to be printed out in a JLabel for display. Here's what I have so far:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class NewBuild extends JFrame
{
private static final int WIDTH = 900;
private static final int HEIGHT = 350;

//Create array constants
private static final String[] WARRIOR = {"7","6","6","5","15","11","5","5","5"};
private static final String[] KNIGHT = {"12","6","7","4","11","8","9","3","6"};
private static final String[] SWORDSMAN =   {"4","8","4","6","9","16","6","7","5"};
private static final String[] BANDIT = {"9","7","11","2","9","14","3","1","8"};
private static final String[] CLERIC =  {"10","3","8","10","11","5","4","4","12"};
private static final String[] SORCERER = {"5","6","5","12","3","7","8","14","4"};
private static final String[] EXPLORER = {"7","6","9","7","6","6","12","5","5"};
private static final String[] DEPRIVED = {"6","6","6","6","6","6","6","6","6"};
private static final String[] CLASS_NAMES = {" ", "Warrior", "Knight", "SwordsMan", "Bandit", "Cleric", "Sorcerer", "Explorer", "Deprived"};



private int num;
private int count = 0;
private String classes;

Container newBuildWindow = getContentPane();

private JLabel lblBuildName, lblStartingClass, lblDisplayStartingStats;

private JTextField txtBuildName;

private JComboBox cStartingClasses;


public NewBuild()
{
    GUI();

}//End of Constructor

public void GUI()
{
    this.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    newBuildWindow.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    setTitle("New Build");
    setLayout(new GridLayout(5,2));
    setVisible(true);
//  setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,3));

    lblBuildName = new JLabel("Build Name");
    lblBuildName.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
    panel1.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    panel1.add(lblBuildName);

    txtBuildName = new JTextField(15);
    txtBuildName.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    panel1.add(txtBuildName);

    lblStartingClass = new JLabel("Pick a starting class:");
    lblStartingClass.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
    lblDisplayStartingStats = new JLabel("Default");
    lblDisplayStartingStats.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
    cStartingClasses = new JComboBox(CLASS_NAMES);

    cStartingClasses.addItemListener(new itemChangeListener());



    panel2.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    panel2.add(lblStartingClass);
    panel2.add(cStartingClasses);
    panel2.add(lblDisplayStartingStats);


    //add panels to pane
    newBuildWindow.add(panel1);
    newBuildWindow.add(panel2);
//  pack();

}//End of GUI method

class itemChangeListener implements ItemListener
{
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
        {



        }

    }

}






}//End of class NewBuild
```

Any help would be very much appreciated...Please don't just post a solution, I want to understand the code not copy it.

Comment: Wrap the "sub arrays" in POJO, which has a description which can be printed in the `JComboBox`, this way, when the user selects an item, you simply extract the associated array

Comment: FYI: [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object). If this were my project, I'd work on OOP-ifying it first -- making valid OOP-compliant classes with states and behaviors -- **before** trying to make a GUI out of it.

Answer (score 1):

First, create a "wrapper" class which can bind the `String` values to a particular name (before anyone rushes at me says you can use a `Map` of some kind, you could, but this "carries" the associated information within a neat package)

```
public class ClassType {

    private String description;
    private String[] values;

    public ClassType(String description, String[] values) {
        this.description = description;
        this.values = values;
    }

    public String[] getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return description;
    }

}
```

Build an array of these `ClassType`s and give this to the `JComboBox`

```
    ClassType[] types = new ClassType[]{
        new ClassType("Warrior", WARRIOR),
        new ClassType("Knight", KNIGHT),
        new ClassType("Swordsman", SWORDSMAN),
        new ClassType("Bandit", BANDIT),
        new ClassType("Cleric", CLERIC),
        new ClassType("Socerer", SORCERER),
        new ClassType("Explorer", EXPLORER),
        new ClassType("Deprived", DEPRIVED)
    };

    cStartingClasses = new JComboBox(types);
```

And when the `ItemListener` is notified, extract the values from the selected item...

```
@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
        ClassType classType = (ClassType) ((JComboBox)e.getSource()).getSelectedItem();
        if (classType != null) {
            String values[] = classType.getValues();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm trying this out, but how do I get it to display in my JLabel?

Comment: Display what?  This was kind of sticking point for me.  I can get the list of attributes for a given class, but what did you want to display?

Comment: Exactly what I posted at the top of my post...I want to select one of my items from my comboBox and if they Select Warrior for instance, I want the WARRIOR[] (all the values) to display in my JLabel called lblDisplayStartingStats.  That way the user knows which base stats the class they chose comes with.

Comment: lblDisplayStartingStats.setText(Arrays.toString(values));

Answer (score 0):

You can get the index and item as:

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
        {
           int index = cStartingClasses.getSelectedIndex();
           String item = String.valueOf(cStartingClasses.getSelectedItem());
        }
    }
```

Here `cStartingClasses` is `JcomboBox`.

Comment: I realize I can get the index this way, however this isn't what I'm trying to achieve.